# How to detect key-points that lies on the ground plane?

Tags: geometry, homography, keypoint

I have two images from the same video sequence.
I find correspondent key-points on them as follows

[image]
[image]

My goal is to detect the homography that relates both ground planes in image 1 and image 2 (without calibrating the camera).

So my current problem is: How can I know which points are on the ground plane? or How can I detect correspondant points that lies on the ground plane?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: Does anyone have a small idea :)? thank you in advance!

Comment: You actually need 3D information to do this, which could be extracted by overlapping images. Having a stereo-pair would help, but the parallax in your images is too little.Alternatively, you could try some kind of image segmentation to detect the road region.